# Is there any way to map two links in a JAXB XML entity to different classes?

Tags: rest, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

Is there any way to map two links in a JAXB XML entity to different classes? 
Example:

```
<restresource>
  <atom:link rel="http://myuri/rels/author" href="http://myuri/users/42" title="That's me"/>
  <atom:link rel="http://myuri/rels/customer" href="http://myuri/customers/4711" title="John Smith"/>
</restresource>
```

I'd like to map the first link with a XMLAdapter to the class User and the second one with a different XMLAdapter to class Customer. I tried to do that with @XmlPath from [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php). But didn't got any result from a lot of experiments since it's not possible to define a path with conditions on "rel". I understand that this could only be done in combination with the Adaptor because otherwise the definition would not be bidirectional. 
Any idea how to realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've added an extension to [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)'s [@XmlPath](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html) that will make this use case easier to map.  In EclipseLink 2.3 you will be able to do the following:

```
@XmlPath("atom:link[@rel='http://myuri/rels/author'])
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AuthorAdapter.class)
private Author author;

@XmlPath("atom:link[@rel='http://myuri/rels/customer'])
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomerAdapter.class)
private Customer customer;
```

You can try this [feature](https://bugs.eclipse.org/339596) out today by downloading one of the EclipseLink 2.3.0 nightly downloads (starting March 22) from:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

**For more information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

I will also try to put together an approach that is compatible with released versions of [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php).

Comment: Cool! Looking forward to check this out.

Comment: @MyMacAndMe - This functionality is now available in the EclipseLink 2.3.0 stream.  I have updated my answer with the details.